# Do I need to normalize this MySQL db?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, database, search

I have a classifieds website which uses SOLR to search for whatever ads the user wants to search for... SOLR then returns the ID:s of all the matches found. I then use the ID:s to fetch and display the ads from a MySQL table.

currently I have one huge table containing everything in MySQL.
Sometimes some of the fields are empty because for instance an apartment has no "model" but a car does.

Is this a problem for me if I use SOLR like I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask yourself these questions:

- Is your current implementation slow or prone to error?
- Are you adding a lot of "hacks" in order to display content or fetch data correctly due to the de-normalization of your database?
- In the long run, will you benefit from normalizing the table?

Hope that helps. It all depends on your situation! Personally, I build databases normalized and then de-normalize as needed to keep things speedy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SOLR, why don't you just serve complete ad from solr instead of MySQL to save DB time?

One huge table usually is not goog option at all.